# Unfortunately (app_name) has stopped ANDROID ECLIPSE

Tags: android

here is the problem. I'm new with android so i was just designing a simple form with some textfields and button, nothing complicated, and it runs perfectly![image: THIS IS IT]

Nevertheless when i add another class in order to work with SQLite database, it doesn't run, and shows the following message: "UNFORTUNATELY, HAS STOPPED"

Please if u have any idea 'bout to fix this problema i'll be more than thankful.

PS: i'm using the ADT BUNDLE FOR WINDOWS which has Eclipse, sdk, sdk manager. just for the record.[image: the problem]

...And just in case u ask me for the log error here it is:
[image: The log error]

Guys thanks a lot for your help! i know it's kinda boring but thanks anyway.
Here is the manifest should i add the new activity in this part of the code or where?
[image: maniefest]

Comment: Please post your Logcat.

Comment: you might not have added the other activity to manifest file ;)

Comment: Whenever you see the "Unfortunately your app has stopped", it should be translated as "Please, look into the LogCat". The problem is in your code, and the LogCat will provide you with information about the cause of the error, and even the line number that generated that error.

Comment: I just added the log error so may help u help me!

Comment: Good, you posted the LogCat, now look for a line in the stacktrace that begins with `Caused by: ...`. That line will tell you the cause of the error and the line number where it occured in your `MainActivity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you created a new activity?

every activity created must be added to the manifest file of the app otherwise the app will crash when that activity is started.

heres how you add it to the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.android.test.ActivityName"
        android:label="@string/activity_label" ></activity>
```

where `com.android.test.ActivityName` is the name of the activity as it appears in the package
add that between the `<application> </application>` tags

Comment: Ryan Hurling: there i just posted my manifest file, should i enter the code u just told me, or where?

Comment: you enter it between `<application>` and `</application>` tags, but not in another activities tag, post it after the first `</activity>` as that is when your main activities tag ends... also make a label for it in the `strings.xml` file and reference it for the label or if you want it to use your apps name just do `"@string/app_name"`

Comment: I believe it'll work, but my problem is that i'm not sure what to modify, but thanks for the guidance Ryan Hurling! (Y)

Comment: well your package is `formulario.formulario` so for you the app name is: `android:name="formulario.formulario.ActivityName" and your label can just be `android:label="@string/app_name"` so place:

`<activity android:name="formulario.formulario.ActivityName" android:label="@string/app_name"> </activity>` and place that between the `<application>` tags